# Google Sheets Formula For Separating Items in a List

Tags: google-sheets, join, split, flatten, textjoin

I'm looking for help in writing a Google Sheets formula in Cell C1 with an input of this range in A1:B1 :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 122, 123, 124 | Apple, Orange, Pear |

and get an output of this:

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | Apple, Orange, Pear |
| 123 | Apple, Orange, Pear |
| 124 | Apple, Orange, Pear |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, ",")&"×"&B1), "×"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I was on the right track but wouldn't have gotten there.